# How to define file type when I want to extend existing type

Tags: typescript

I use an existing native type `File`, and I need to extend it with field `id`. Now I have something like this:

```
type FileWithId = File & {
  id: number;
};

const ATTACHMENTS = [
  {
    name: "some_file_name.txt",
    ...
  },
  {
    name: "some_file_name2.txt",
    ...
  }
];

const files = ATTACHMENTS.map((attachment) => {
  const file: FileWithId = new File([], attachment.name);
  file.id = attachment.id;
  return file;
});
```

But TypeScript show an error:

```
TS2322: Type 'File' is not assignable to type 'Attachment'.
    Property 'id' is missing in type 'File' but required in type '{ id: number; }'.
```

If I remove casting type `FileWithId` on `file` then there error:

```
TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'File'.
```

Making field `id` optional solve the problem here but it cause errors in other places, btw I need to show that `id` is required property in my type.

Casting type like this:

```
const file = new File([], attachment.name) as FileWithId;
```

isn't good idea for some reasons

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `id` to the `File` and then return that, without using a variable:

```
const files = ATTACHMENTS.map((attachment) => Object.assign(new File([], attachment.name), { id: attachment.id }));
```

You can also use spreading:

```
const files = ATTACHMENTS.map((attachment) => ({ ...new File([], attachment.name), id: attachment.id }));
```

Comment: I don't know why, but things with spreading didn't work on `new File(...)`, I got and object with only `id` field.
Thing with `Object.assign` working good.

But question mostly about is there a way to solve this proplem with typings? Maybe with some complex generics or some tricky extending.

Comment: The properties must not be enumerable then. You can still use `Object.assign`.